# Populating an existing table with only difference from a full file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I'm going to populate a table with 4 columns date, budget, cs, adrr every night. The problem is that i will read from a full file every night. So for example the first night the file will have these values:

> 206-04-19 | 30000 | 566 | Fantasy road 1|

And the nex night the file will have these values:

> 206-04-19 | 30000 | 566 | Fantasy road 1|
>
> 206-04-20 | 32000 | 456 | Imagine crossings 44|

So for each night the file will have increased rows (will be more than just 1 row).
What would be the best way to populate this table? Drop the table every night before populating it, or is there a way to only populate rows that don't exist in the table? I would prefer to use SSIS as a full solution but I'm also willing to use any other solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: As I understood: date - is unique field for your data. So, you can upload file to some temp table and insert only not existing dates. If you will only add new rows to file, you can select last added date and insert only records with date > last.

Comment: it depends on how big the file will grow... I would build an audit Delta table (Today - Yesterday) to insert only the new data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple more considerations you need to think about that may change your approach to this. You've mentioned new data, have you a possibility of data being deleted or modified between days? If no, then I'd recommend either a NOT EXISTS or by using an outer join with an IS NULL predicate in a where clause. If you do have the possibility of deletions/modifications to existing data then you'd be better looking at either a full truncate (beware of log files and statistics if this is the case) or running a MERGE between the new file and the old data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a staging table where you can bulk insert/insert the data, and then do an insert where not exists in the destination table.